# Dark mode keeps turning off in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.10

I've just upgraded to 22.10 and one thing is annoying the hell out of me: the dark mode setting in the new "quick settings" pod is switching off all the time (I even can't figure out when it happens). Did anyone noticed the same?

Comment: "Did anyone noticed the same?" Is that all you want to know? If so... it is an answer that if "no" is likely to be a temporary "no". We do not do surveys on AU. Describe the problem as best as possible and ask for a possible solution or workaround. OR what would be getting quicker results: file a bug report against ""quick settings"-pod Then again it is also likely that if this is a bug it will get fixed anyways. Prepare for a couple of days where bug fixes get released. You are paying the price for installing so quickly ;-) I tend to wait a few days myself if it is an interim release

Comment: @Rinzwind Actually it would be enough - if that's a common problem I'll just wait for the official fix, if not - will have to figure it out by myself. But I guess any reasonable user with a solution would just post it :)

Comment: Yeah, happened to me with the Beta on a Dell Inspiron 5437. I thought it would be a problem with extensions and themes, but even in a barebones installation it happened.

Comment: I upgrade to 22.10 last night and have the same problem.
Looks like only the new "Quick Settings" menu of Gnome 43 and the "Notifications/calendar menu" are affected, other aplications like Nautilus works fine. I cant figure out any kind of pattern or cause/effect for this bug. Let's wait for a oficial fix.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, in my case the option turns off when I open the Settings app.

Comment: yes, I noticed this and reported it as soon as I upgraded. Until this is fixed, you basically want to set it to Dark using the Quick Menu and avoid going into the Appearance section of the Settings app (gnome-control-center). You can add your experience here, it might help giving the bug some extra visibility with the devs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1993874

Answer (score 4):

I noticed the same right now. Maybe I found the solution. Just install GNOME Tweaks, go to *Appearance*, and make sure you set your default and *Legacy Applications* themes to your own.

It appears that this bug is caused by the User Themes extension when you haven't configured it.