# Default Dark Mode not fully working on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: themes, gnome-panel, 22.10, appearance, mode

I'm trying to use default dark mode on Ubuntu 22.10, however widgets on the top bar (GNOME panel) remain on light mode.

[image]

[image]
I tried Tweak but even with that I couldn't fix it.

Note: I have been upgrading Ubuntu in my computer with any new version since 19.04

Any help would be really appreciated.

Related to: [Dark mode keeps turning off in Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436549/dark-mode-keeps-turning-off-in-ubuntu-22-10)

Comment: It seems like that this bug starts to happen when one change the background picture. Before the change dark theme works fine. https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/yfqa2c/ubuntu_2210_dark_mode_bug/

Comment: Thank you for the link, hopefully this would be fixed soon!

Answer (score 3):

I also tried changing the settings in the Tweaks application, but it still didn't work. Later I changed the theme in *User Themes* by enabling User Themes in *Extensions* (or Extension Manager) and took the dark theme of my default theme (in my case it's Yaru-dark).

[image: screenshot-userthemes.png]

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me. What *did* work in the end (assuming of course your settings everywhere show a dark theme as selected) was pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing `r`, this refreshes all windows.